# android devices in landscape mode display double scrolling

Tags: codenameone

Android device show double scrolling when the form is long. Please find the attached screenshot. Please advise what can be done to avoid this double scrolling.

Thanks

Comment: This is because you have nested scrollables which is a bug in that form. FYI this is portrait mode